# Configuración dinámica según parametro de request (spring boot)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

Esta es mi primer pregunta que he intentado buscar en esta fantástica página, pero no di con la solución.

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo un *REST API* que tiene un *service* que le pega a un servicio web de un tercero y cuyo *service* tiene su clase `config` y también su clase `properties` para levantar parámetros del `application.properties`.

Todo está andando perfecto. Mi problema es que este servicio web que consumo desde el *service*, esta deployado en los ambientes *stage* y *prod* y según un parámetro que recibe mi *REST API* en el *request* me debe determinar a qué *endpoint* debo apuntar, si al de *stage* o *prod*.

Ya intenté obtener el *request* actual en la clase de configuración con:

`((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest()`

Pero dado que es inyectado automáticamente, apenas inicializa mi *REST API* tira excepciones y no inicializa.

**Definir distintos tipos de `properties`, según el *profile* no es válido en este caso porque mi *REST API* está siempre deployada en el mismo servidor y debo resolverlo utilizando un solo *profile*.**

Personalmente pienso que debe existir algún mecanismo en *spring* para resolver este tipo de problemas.

Comment: podrías explicar como recibes el parámetro del ambiente en tu servició rest  de ser posible coloca un ejemplo de Código sobre el cual proporcionarte una respuesta, si quieres mezclar propiedades de distintos perfiles no es posible, lo que debes hacer es en un solo perfil manejar las propiedades de ambos ambientes por ejemplo para una url `prod.url=http` y `stage.url=https` luego es tu servicio obtienes las propiedad según el parametro que recibas.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo pude solucionar, lo que realice es crear un POJO intermedio que tenga request scope y popular este con el atributo del request en el controller. Y como utilizo autowire en el service config tuve que crear todos los clientes de una vez para luego al momento de utilizarlo, leo el POJO para saber que cliente utilizo. Muchas gracias por intentar ayudar.